# uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var z, key, elem, a = [];
var all_check = document.querySelectorAll('label.check');
for (var i = 0; i < all_check.length; i++) {
  key = all_check[i].parentElement.dataset.params;
  elem = all_check[i].querySelector("span.label").innerText;
  a[key][i] = [3];
  z += all_check[i].querySelector("span.label").innerText + ";";
}
```

не могу понять почему выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[key]` - неопределено, так как `а` - пустой массив.

```
...
if (a[key] == undefined) {
  a[key] = [];
}
a[key][i] = [3];
...
```